# Chainlink Functions unauthorized sender error when calling createSubscription

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm currently trying to utilize **Chainlink** functions and am following the tutorial at https://blog.thirdweb.com/guides/chainlink-functions/.

However, I get stuck when calling **createSubscription** from the **FunctionsBillingRegistry** at 0xEe9Bf52E5Ea228404bB54BCFbbDa8c21131b9039 as it seems like the function call is only for authorized users.

This is the full error that I get:

call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="createSubscription()", data="0x08094908", errorArgs=[], errorName="UnauthorizedSender", errorSignature="UnauthorizedSender()", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

Comment: Chainlink functions is in beta test and you have to make an application to Chainlink labs to add your address(in polygon Mumbai or Sepolia) in the whitelist to use it. The application form is [here](https://chainlinkcommunity.typeform.com/requestaccess)